# Python - How to return a double with eval()

Tags: python, eval

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find anything on it.

I'm new to python and I'm making a calculator using Tkinter. With the evaluation of the equation entered, it will only return decimals if you use a decimal in the equation. For example, if you type in 3/2 it will return 1. Is there any way to return answers as a double other than creating my own method for each problem type?

code:

```
def enter(self):
    answer = self.text.get(0.0, END)
    answer = eval(answer)
    self.text.delete(0.0, END)
    self.text.insert(END, answer)
```

Comment: This is *not* the way to write a calculator. You should be parsing the input string, not using `eval` at all. `eval` is `evil`.

Comment: To be fair, parsing/evaluating arbitrary infix operations yourself is not trivial, and slapping `eval` in there is a one-line implementation.  It's reasonable to put `eval` in, write the rest of your program around it, then swap it out for your own much-safer implementation later.  (then wash your hands because use of `eval` makes you feel *unclean*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python2, either import `__future__`, or convert to float first.

Importing `__future__`:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> eval('3/2')
1.5
>>>
```

Or call the numbers with a trailing `0`:

```
>>> eval('3.0/2.0')
1.5
>>>
```

However, the `from __future__ import division` is only necessary in python2, because by default the *future* versions of python call this.

When you import `__future__`, the division applies for **all** future equations you work on.

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 10/9
1.1111111111111112
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>> 7/8
0.875
>>> 7/9
0.7777777777777778
>>>
```

Comment: Importing `__future__` does nothing; only the `from __future__ import whatever` form is magic.

Comment: Edited, you beat me by 27 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

To get floating-point division for integer inputs in Python 2, use

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your code, before everything else. Note that this will affect the whole file, not just the `eval`.